# Why does my jquery onclick function toggle on and off, if I run initialization more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with a few icons/buttons that trigger a simple menu when you click them. However, I need to be able to load more data, with more of these buttons, and  since the existing buttons are initialized with a function, using jquery onclick, i figured I would just re-run that function whenever the number of buttons are changed.

I expected the existing onclick functions to be simply overwritten, with the same content as before. Even though it is not optimal code, I expected it to work fast, and simple.

But then I discovered that running the onclick initializing function simply toggles the working elements. In other words the newly generated elements now works, but the existing ones does not. Calling the function a third time toggles them all back, meaning the original works, but not the new. This baffles me.

[I made a JSFiddle, showing what I mean:](http://jsfiddle.net/d9ebg74f/)

To see the different scenarios of original state, added button and toggled, and thirdly toggled back, just comment out lines in the document ready function in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initContextMenuButtons(); //initializes cog-icon buttons
  addThirdButton(); //adds a third button, and calls init again, toggling all
  initContextMenuButtons(); //toggles back
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="relative-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-cog context-menu-button"></i>
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <div class="tooltip">
        <div class="edit-button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit button</div>
        <div class="delete-button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete button</div>
        <div class="close-button"><i class="fa fa-fh fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="tooltip-arrow-wrapper"><b class="tooltip-arrow"></b></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="relative-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-cog context-menu-button"></i>
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <div class="tooltip">
        <div class="edit-button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit button</div>
        <div class="delete-button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete button</div>
        <div class="close-button"><i class="fa fa-fh fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="tooltip-arrow-wrapper"><b class="tooltip-arrow"></b></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initContextMenuButtons();
  addThirdButton();
  initContextMenuButtons();
});

function initContextMenuButtons() {
  $('.context-menu-button').click(function() {
    var this_wrapper = $(this).siblings(".tooltip-wrapper").toggle();
    $(".tooltip-wrapper").not(this_wrapper).hide();
  });

  $('.tooltip .close-button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".tooltip-wrapper").hide();
  });
}

function addThirdButton() {
  var html = ' <div class="relative-wrapper">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-2x fa-cog context-menu-button"></i>' +
    '<div class="tooltip-wrapper">' +
    '<div class="tooltip">' +
    '<div class="edit-button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit button</div>' +
    '<div class="delete-button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete button</div>' +
    '<div class="close-button"><i class="fa fa-fh fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>' +
    '<div class="tooltip-arrow-wrapper"><b class="tooltip-arrow"></b></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
  $('#wrapper').append(html);
  initContextMenuButtons();
}
```

CSS:

```
.relative-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip .close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 1px;
  color: #999;
}

.tooltip .close-button:hover {
  color: #555;
}

.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 38px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px 0px;
}

.tooltip .edit-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 185px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.milestone-tooltip .edit-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tooltip .delete-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 185px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip .delete-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tooltip-arrow-wrapper {
  height: 24.8px;
  width: 16px;
  display: block;
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  left: -14px;
  top: 11px;
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip-arrow {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  transform: translate(8px, 4px) rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
}

.context-menu-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Existing event handlers don't get overwritten. The new event handlers simply stack on top of them. One click now fires the event multiple times. Use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead, allowing your single click event to inherently handle dynamically-created elements.

Comment: that makes perfect sense. A toggle will actually fire twice. Or three times. thanks a lot

Comment: Just change your click event to `$(document).on('click', '.tooltip .close-button', function() { ... });` instead and you will never have to worry about re-attaching the events at all. It will work for new elements as well as existing ones.

Comment: because it is bound to the parent document, instead of each individual element?

Comment: That's correct. The event handler is on the parent, and essentially any time an event 
(like a click) bubbles up, the document says *"Was this fired by `'.tooltip .close-button'`? Yes? Fire the event. No? Ignore it."*. Because it's checking *at the time of the click*, it doesn't matter if it is a new element or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing event handlers don't get overwritten. The new event handlers simply stack on top of them. One click now fires the event multiple times.

I'd highly recomment using [**Event Delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for the following reasons:

- Dynamically created elements will just *work*. No need to attach new events.
- With your current method, hypothetically, if you have 10 elements, that's 10 event handlers. Event delegation allows you to have just **1**, whether you have 1 element or 1,000.
- It's nearly identical to your existing code. You're simply attaching the event to the `document` instead of the element itself.

```js
function initContextMenuButtons() {
  $(document).on('click', '.context-menu-button', function() {
    var this_wrapper = $(this).siblings(".tooltip-wrapper").toggle();
    $(".tooltip-wrapper").not(this_wrapper).hide();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.tooltip .close-button', function() {
    $(this).closest(".tooltip-wrapper").hide();
  });
}
```

`initContextMenuButtons()` should now only be fired **once** throughout the life of the page, so be sure to remove the call from your `addThirdButton()` method, as well as the second call from your `$(document).ready( ... )`.

Comment: I decided to switch, and make this the accepted answer. I just added a short paragraph from your comment, explaining what is happening in my original code. Otherwise the answer would not actually answer the question. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your event listeners add up. To make multiple initializations work, you can remove existing ones first.

```
$('.context-menu-button').off().click(function() {
// ...
$('.tooltip .close-button').off().click(function() {
```

In general, you can also [use namespaces](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to prevent accidentally removing other event listeners.

```
$('.context-menu-button').off('.init').on('click.init', function() {
// ...
$('.tooltip .close-button').off('.init').on('click.init', function() {
```

Comment: I like this. And it answers the question. I think I will go for another approach though, and add a 'initialized'-class to the ones who has been initialized. And then add a :not('.initialized') to the selector. Thanks for making me understand how this works!

Comment: ...and done. Systems are functional. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Remove *initContextMenuButtons()* function and its references. Add the following code.

```
 $('#wrapper').on('click', '.context-menu-button', function () {
  var this_wrapper = $(this).siblings(".tooltip-wrapper").toggle();
      $(".tooltip-wrapper").not(this_wrapper).hide();
});

$('#wrapper').on('click', '.tooltip .close-button', function() {
    $(this).closest(".tooltip-wrapper").hide();
});
```

Comment: The dynamically created elements will not have events attached to them using this method. If you're suggesting that they add this code *also* when the new elements are created, you'll still have the issue that OP has - you'll re-attached the events to existing elements.